# Increase font size of the folded code tooltip in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I want to increase font size of the tooltip that Visual Studio shows when hovering mouse cursor over a folded code block (pointed out in the image below).

[image: Folded code tooltip]

It isn't affected by Tools – Options – Environment – Fonts and Colors – Show settings for – Editor Tooltip. Where is the setting that changes it?